# Mongoose Populate return empty array with joining and generating children from other table

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have looked at all of the cases on StackOverflow but I could not fix this error:
You can find the whole code here :
[Link to SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-http-n4fcs?file=/src/index.js:454-1179)
I have 2 collections: "pars" for parents and "chil" for children

**pars:**

[image: Pars Collection]

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "607091fa48ea8376b9398ba7"
  },
  "name": "ParA"
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6070920748ea8376b9398ba8"
  },
  "name": "ParB"
}]
```

**chil:**

[image: Chils Collection]

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6070921648ea8376b9398ba9"
  },
  "name": "Chil1",
  "parRef": {
    "$ref": "chils",
    "$id": {
      "$oid": "6070920748ea8376b9398ba8"
    }
  },
  "parId": "6070920748ea8376b9398ba8"
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6070922648ea8376b9398baa"
  },
  "name": "Chil2",
  "parRef": {
    "$ref": "chils",
    "$id": {
      "$oid": "607091fa48ea8376b9398ba7"
    }
  },
  "parId": "607091fa48ea8376b9398ba7"
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6070923348ea8376b9398bab"
  },
  "name": "Chil3",
  "parRef": {
    "$ref": "chils",
    "$id": {
      "$oid": "607091fa48ea8376b9398ba7"
    }
  },
  "parId": "607091fa48ea8376b9398ba7"
}]
```

I am using **populate** with **mongoose** but it returns an empty array
**Code**

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const getParChil = async () => {
  const schemaPar = new Schema(
    {
      _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      name: String,
      chils: [
        {
          type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: "modelChil"
        }
      ]
    },
    { collection: "pars" }
  );

  const schemaChil = new Schema(
    {
      _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      name: String,
      parId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "modelPar" }
    },
    { collection: "chils" }
  );

  const modelChil = mongoose.model("modelChil", schemaChil);
  const modelPar = mongoose.model("modelPar", schemaPar);

  const res = await modelPar.find({}).populate("chil");
  console.log("result", res);
};

getParChil();
```

**response:**

```
[
  { chils: [], _id: 607091fa48ea8376b9398ba7, name: 'ParA' },
  { chils: [], _id: 6070920748ea8376b9398ba8, name: 'ParB' }
]
```

Please advise. I would like to join these two tables and get the result like this:
**expected behaviour**

```
[
{
_id: 607091fa48ea8376b9398ba7, 
name:"ParA",
chils:[{"name":"Chil2"},{"name":"Chil3"}]
},
{
_id: 6070920748ea8376b9398ba8,
name:"ParB",
chils:[{"name":"Chil1"}]
}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should reference the model name and not the collection name:

```js
const schemaPar = new Schema(
  {
    _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name: String,
    chils: [
      {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Chil",  // change made here 
      },
    ],
  },
  { collection: "pars" }
);

const schemaChil = new Schema(
  {
    _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name: String,
    parId: { 
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
      ref: "Par" // change made here
     }, 
  },
  { collection: "chils" }
);


modelChil=mongoose.model("Chil", schemaChil);
modelPar=mongoose.model("Par", schemaPar);
```

Comment: Thanks for your valid advice. I have changed but still, I am missing something. I appreciate any hint. I have uploaded codes and connection to db here:

[link](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-http-n4fcs?file=/src/index.js:454-1179)

Comment: First of all try to avoid putting database accesses in publicly available pages.

But thanks to that I was able to connect to your database and see that your parent documents didn't have child references, only your childs had parent references.

When you use populate mongoose is using the field on the document itself to find the referenced document(s). In your case those fields were just not saved on the parent documents.

Comment: Another note is that you were calling populate on a (non-existent) `chil` field on the parent and not `chils` with this line: `modelPar.find({}).populate("chil");`

Comment: Thanks dear @Mayer. Then there is no way to use "populate" if we have only reference in child? (like a foreign key of usual SQL tables). I know it is not a correct pattern to use MongoDB as relational DB but this is how they have already implemented?

Comment: No, but populate is just a convenience method, you can achieve the same result if you query all childs where `parId` is `$in` the array of parent ids and then map the result on the correct parents

Comment: Thanks for your help, really appreciated, can you kindly advise some code for your guidance, please?

Comment: `const parents = await modelPar.find({}); const children = await modelChil.find({ parId: { $in: parents.map(p => p._id) }});` Now you can just map the two together by comparing the ids of the parents to the child's `parId` field